# Override an SQLCMD variable inside a T-SQL script

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sqlcmd

I have written this T-SQL code that I ran in SQLCMD Mode in SSMS:

```
:setvar ENV "Table1"

DECLARE @DomainPrefix NVARCHAR(50) = N'$(ENV)';

IF(@DomainPrefix = N'Table1')
BEGIN
    SET @DomainPrefix = 'Table2';
END;

:setvar Prefix @DomainPrefix

PRINT $(Prefix)

SELECT * FROM [DATA].[mySchema].[$(Prefix)]
```

The given output is the following:

> Table2 
>   Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 12 Invalid object name
>   'DATA.mySchema.@DomainPrefix'.

I don't understand why it is not replacing $(DomainPrefix) by the value 'Table2' that I am able to print on the previous line.

Comment: Replacement is literal. So the `$(Prefix)` gets replaced with `@DomainPrefix`, giving you the "object name" `[@DomainPrefix]`. (`PRINT @DomainPrefix` of course works fine.) The SQLCMD macro system has no knowledge whatsoever of what T-SQL actually looks like, or what T-SQL variables are. Since you can't use variable names in a `FROM`, you will never be able to use them by SQLCMD replacement either -- that requires dynamic SQL no matter what.

Comment: Thank you now I understand. Is there a way to set up the same conditional logic using only sqlcmd syntax in order to define my variable $(Prefix) before any T-SQL commands?

Comment: No. The SQLCMD macro system is not an actual programming language and has nothing in the way of conditionals or expressions. It also completely ignores any `IF`s in the T-SQL code (because, again, it doesn't "read" any of that). What you can do is something like `:setvar ENV Table1`, `:setvar ENV2 Table2` and then replace these values in T-SQL to do actual conditionals (with what would look like constants to the T-SQL code), or else of course build completely dynamic SQL.

Comment: Ok thanks. Going back to your first answer, since SQLCMD has no knowledge of T-SQL, why did my PRINT output a 'Table2' instead of '@DomainPrefix' ?